# Unsubscribe to lambda event

Tags: c#, events, lambda

I have subscribed to an event using lambda to add a parameter so i dont ont have one eventhandler to execute the code, but how can i unsubscribe to this:

Subscribe:

```
value.rZone1.onValueChanged += (sender, e) => rZone_onValueChanged(sender, e, 1);
```

Eventhandler:

```
void rZone_onValueChanged(IHoldingRegisterBit sender, HoldingRegisterBitValueChangedEventArgs e, int ZoneID)
            {

            }
```

Unsubscribe: ?????

Comment: I dont think it is a duplicate, how would i send that int with the eventhandler, if i create a delegate like that?

Comment: @Jeff The same way you would if you used a lambda; the whole point of the answer is simply to maintain a reference to the lambda, that's all.

Comment: @Servy, Could you show me how to do this, with keeping one end function and add parameters?

Comment: You do it exactly as you are now, you just hold onto a reference to the lambda.